# Why DISTINCT OF MYSQL does not remove duplication?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a query in MYSQL which contains compnay name, ticker and total return of the 20 stocks that performed worst from 2020-11-09 to 2020-11-10.
The firt problem DISTINCT does not help me remove duplication, I expected to remove duplication by permno, but the output is still duplicated as comnam and tickers are different for the same permno and ret, even though they are just in parent company and son company relationship.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUqHu.png)
How should I get unique permno row?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT permno, date, ret, ticker, comnam
    FROM crsp.dsf as a 
    INNER JOIN crsp.dsenames as b 
    USING (permno) 
    WHERE date >='2020-11-09' AND date <='2020-11-10'
    ORDER BY ret DESC 
    limit 20;
```

Second Problem should be cause by GROUP BY, when I am trying to add function to get total return of 20 stocks, always error nomatter how I tried :(

```
    SELECT DISTINCT permno, date, ret, ticker, comnam
    exp(sum(log(1+ret))) as "total return"
    FROM crsp.dsf as a 
    INNER JOIN crsp.dsenames as b 
    USING (permno) 
    WHERE date >='2020-11-09' AND date <='2020-11-10'
    group by permno
    ORDER BY ret DESC 
    limit 20;
```

Comment: What do you expect as output for the other columns when you only want one occurrence for `permno`? To take the example in your screenshot: for permno 18,047, should the ticker display GLAC or GTEC (when you only have one line)?

Comment: *The firt problem DISTINCT does not help me remove duplication, I expected to remove duplication by permno* Duplicate is **complete** duplicate only - i.e. the values in **all** columns must be identical for two rows to be duplicates. If at least one column value differs then these rows are not dups. Use GROUP BY **and according aggregate functions**.

Comment: In the second and third row of the screenshot, the name of company and ticker are different, but their ret and permno are the same. As they have the same return and permno, so I would still consider they as duplication as I want to find out the worst 20 return in the two days, it doesn't make sense to have more than one exactly the same return and permno. I want to keep only one distinct return row no matter it goes with Greenland Acquisition or Greenland Tech HLDG @ Akina,@trincot